# Can QWidgets be added to QWindow?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qwidget

It's now recommended to use QWindow for OpenGL drawing. Is it possible to add a widget to this window? If so, how? If not, how should I go about adding widgets to an OpenGL program using Qt5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Qt form class from a custom window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23929301/how-to-create-a-qt-form-class-from-a-custom-window)

Comment: How should your final result look like? You could think of going the other way around -- embedding your GL window into a QWidget hierarchy by using `QWidget::createWindowContainer`.

Comment: @peppe The problem with QWidget::createWindowContainer is that it prevents me from calling methods from the window object that was passed in. It also makes it impossible to inherit from.

Comment: Why does it prevent such a thing?! Use the `QWidget *` it returns for its UI management (layouting, etc.); use the `YourWindow *` you pass to it for anything else (logic).

Comment: @peppe Any changes I make to the window object after creating the container seem to have no effect on the widget.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An application will typically use `QWidget` or `QQuickView` for its UI, and not `QWindow` directly. `QWindow` is more low level than `QWidget`. If you want to use `QWindow` directly, more work is needed to accomplish the job. You should manually do all drawing related things which is not easy.

However, if you really want a `QWindow`/`QGuiApplication` instead of `QWidget`/`QApplication`, you can use [QBackingStore](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qbackingstore.html) which is used by `QWidget`, or `SceneGraph` which is used by `QQuick` in `QWindow::exposeEvent()`.

You can see an example of a minimal `QWindow` based application using `QPainter` [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtgui-rasterwindow-example.html).